# Will I get Null values in the below case?

Tags: oracle

T1--Table having C1 and C2 as columns

```
C1   C2
1    NULL
11   NULL 
111   3
12    4
122   4
12    5
```

How many records will be returned in below case?

```
select * from T1 where C2<> 4
```

Will NULL records be counted or not?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two rows where `c2 <> 4`. These are the rows where `c2` has the values `3` or `5`. Only non-null values can be 'not equal' to something.

This is described in the documentation
[Oracle 12.2 SQL Language Reference: 2.5.3. Nulls in Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html#SQLRF-GUID-C785FE74-5F9C-4F70-AC4B-CA5D3010162A).